# Can I user validator as a service to check who is authorised to delete an entitie

Tags: validation, symfony

If I am right, I can use a validator to check if $comments are created by user that are allowed to post comment

exemple:
let say I have a user entity with a comment_allow attribute which value can be "yes" or "no".

```
/**   
* @comment   
*/   
private $comments
```

The validator

```
class commentvalidator extends ConstraintValidator
if(comments->getAuthor()->getComment_allow() == no)
{
   $this->context->addViolation($constaint->message)
}
```

But can I do something similar to **delete comment** and check with validator that comments is deleted only by its author. So far I do not know where to attached the @commentdelete validator because it is not one the creation but on the removal of the comment that the validation has to be proceeded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for here is a voter.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/voters_data_permission.html